# C# Hidden cmd window require input

Tags: c#, cmd

In my code I need to run a lot of cmd commands. All of them must be hidden. As an example I will show you the code for 2 commands.

```
string cmdText = @"/c regsvr32 vbscript.dll";
System.Diagnostics.Process temp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
temp.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdText;
temp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
temp.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
temp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
temp.Start();
temp.WaitForExit();
cmdText = @"/c regsvr32 jscript.dll";
temp.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdText;
temp.Start();
temp.WaitForExit();
```

Now the problem is that some of the commands(e.g. `gpupdate /force`) require input("Y/N" for example). How do I give this input to a cmd?

Comment: But `gpupdate /force` doesn't have a Y/N prompt. It just runs??????

Comment: @Noodles, on my machine it has. After policies are updated cmd asks if I want to restart my PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the answer is quite easy. To successfully start silent cmd command with a prompt I used following additions(example works fine for `gpupdate /force`)

```
 string cmdText = @"/c echo n | gpupdate /force";
 System.Diagnostics.Process temp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();          
 temp.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdText;
 temp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 temp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 temp.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 temp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 temp.Start();
 temp.WaitForExit();
```

The answer is from [here](http://joejoeinc.blogspot.ru/2010/11/it-took-me-while-to-figure-this-one-out.html). Thanks to [Stephan Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314334/stephan-bauer) for the right direction

As I understood, `echo n` just writes n for a prompt. It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the output of the program and handle it / write the needed input back to the process.
To achieve this, you also need to set some more properties of your Process/ProcessStartInfo:

```
string cmdText = @"/c regsvr32 vbscript.dll";
System.Diagnostics.Process temp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
temp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
temp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
temp.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdText;
temp.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
temp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true;
temp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput=true;
temp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false;
temp.Start();

// Read program's output
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (!temp.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    temp.StandardOutput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    sb.Append(buffer);

    // Check output string and write something back if needed
    if (sb.ToString().Contains("(Yes/No"))
    {
        temp.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
        sb.Clear();
    }
}
temp.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.
Is it the only way to do that? Because it looks like I will need to check every cmd command if it has prompt and what input it requires. It may be a lot of cases if I write a method to work with cmd output/input

Comment: Well some commands do have parameters like `/y` to answer all confirmations with yes. For commands that don't support such a parameter, this is the only solution that comes to my mind at this moment.

Comment: It's stuck when I debug it with `/c gpupdate /force`. On the line `while(!temp.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)` Looks like it can't identify the prompt as the end of a stream.

Comment: Did you add `temp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true;`?

Comment: I just used your code. It stuck if I test it with `/c gpupdate /force`

Comment: I don't know the message that is displayed by gpupdate. Maybe it doesn't contain `(Yes/No`. [This thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4fb40d7b-5512-4c72-be4e-552bf097f1f6) may contain some useful information.

Comment: I don't think it's connected to the text of a prompt. It looks like it can't read std output somewhy